# Rails test db 10x faster than development db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, rspec

I have some seed data that creates 1000 users on my development setup.  Occasionally I reset my db during the development process using this command:

```
rake db:reset
```

It inserts my users at a rate of about 10 users/second.  I thought this was slow but learned to live with it.

I recently ran `db:reset` in the test environment while debugging some rspec tests using this command:

```
rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
```

It inserted users at approximately **100 users/second**!  I can reproduce it and alternate between environments and the dev environment is slow while the test environment is fast.

It is using the exact same mysql setup in `database.yml`:

**Development**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: mydb
  username: mydb
  password: password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```

**Test**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: mydb_test
  username: mydb_test
  password: password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```

This is how I seed the users (same for both environments):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  1000.times do |i|
      User.create :first_name => Faker::Name.first_name, :last_name => Faker::Name.last_name, :email => Faker::Internet.email, :username => Faker::Internet.user_name, :password => '123456'
  end
end
```

Does anyone know what rails is doing to make the test env so fast?  I'd like to implement these settings in the dev environment and speed up my seeding process by 10x.

Comment: Can you add some more details about your seed file and test environment?

Comment: Do you have indexes on users table? Are there lot of users in development database?

Comment: I added the seeding technique.

Comment: There are only these 1000 users.  There is an index called 'reset_password_token' added by devise.

Comment: The weird thing is that its the exact same command, same seed data, same mysql instance.  The only difference is `RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: Are the records actually in your test database when you run a query?

Comment: No, both databases start completely empty when I run the command.

Comment: Sry, after you run the command are the records in the test database?  Just want to make sure there's not some transactional difference.

Comment: Yeah, they're all there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Devise, it could be caused by password stretching. In config/initializers/devise.rb :

```
# Limiting the stretches to just one in testing will increase the performance of
# your test suite dramatically. However, it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to not use
# a value less than 10 in other environments.
config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
```

That seems like difference between development and test envirionments you are looking for. Try playing with this line

Comment: Yes, should be this one

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to implement these settings in the dev environment and speed up my seeding process by 10x.

Bottom line is if you want to insert too many data instantly, you shouldn't consider using rails method. I suffered it.Rails attach too many callbacks like `before_update, after_create` etc .  I have insert 500K data everydata. We have used raw sql to speed up the process. We did something like this

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  inserts = []
  TIMES.times do
   inserts.push "(3.0, '2009-01-23 20:21:13', 2, 1)"
 end
 sql = "INSERT INTO user_node_scores (`score`, `updated_at`, `node_id`, `user_id`) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"
 User.connection.execute  s
end
```

Comment: This is a great technique but I want to know why the environments are so different in terms of performance.